# C++ classes: How does one 'reset' a template field in the move constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

I'm a beginner and I hope I'm not duplicate posting simply because I don't understand terminology, but I've scoured Stack Overflow and Google and still failed to find an answer to my problem, or at least, an answer that I can understand.

I'm writing a Node class for a Singly Linked List assignment.  The class has two fields: elem and next.  Elem is templated and next is a Node pointer.

I decided to write a custom constructor (and thus all the other constructors as well) so I can be sure that next is initialized as nullptr with each new Node, so I don't run into bad pointer issues. The class header:

```
template <typename E>
class Node {
public:

    //Constructors
    Node();
    Node( const Node<E> &other);           //copy
    Node<E>& operator=( Node<E> other );   //copy asn
    Node( Node&& other );                  //move
    Node<E>& operator=( Node<E>&& other ); //move asn
    ~Node();

    // {...Getters and setters and the like...}

private:
    E elem{};       //datatype independent element
    Node<E>* next;  //pointer to next list item
};
```

My problem is with writing the move constructor. From what I understand, the basic outline of a move constructor is as follows:

```
myClass( myClass&& otherMyClassObj ) {

    // Step 1: Steal object's resources

    myClassField = otherMyClassObj.myClassField;
    myClassOtherField = otherMyClassObj.myClassOtherField;
    /* ...etc... */

    // Step 2: Set other object to a valid but default state so it will be deleted

    otherMyClassObj.myClassField = <whatever is default for type>;
    otherMyClassObj.myClassOtherField = <whatever is default for type>;
    /*...etc...*/
}
```

When I attempt to apply this outline to write the move constructor in my class, however, I run into a problem: what is the default state for elem, whose type I do not know because it is determined at runtime? My code for the move constructor:

```
template <typename E>
Node::Node( Node&& other ) {

    next = other.next;
    elem = other.elem;

    other.next = nullptr;
    other.elem = /* ???? */
}
```

The only solution that I can think of is manually calling the destructor on other, but that seems sloppy and wrong.  I can't use nullptr, because elem is not necessarily a pointer, but I can't use 0, because it *could* be one.  Another possibility I considered is calling std::move() directly on elem somehow, but I'm not sure how exactly to do that and it seems inherently wrong to call the move constructor in a move constructor.

I would really appreciate some help on this problem. Please no nonstandard library suggestions -- I'd love to use them, but my professor is very strict about which libraries we use.

Comment: Do you really need to set a default value?  AFAIK a move constructor should leave the moved from object in an unspecified but destructible state

Comment: In the majority of cases, including yours, you should use `std::move` in the move constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have no idea. If I'm writing the move constructor, do I have to do it manually, or does it do it for me?

Comment: @Bathsheba Well that makes so much sense, it was almost too easy. :P

Comment: If you write `template <typename E> Node( Node&& other ) = default` then the compiler will generate the move constructor for you: it will call `std::move` on each member. That has the advantage that your code will not blow up if you add a new member and forget to modify your constructor! Better still, just arrange things so you can *rely* on the compiler generating the move constructor implicitly.

Comment: @Bathsheba So if I understand correctly, your suggestion and Werner Henze's suggestion below accomplish the same thing, but yours automatically moves each member and in his the members to move must be specified?

Comment: Yup. That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move each member.

```
template <typename E>
Node::Node<E>( Node<E> && other ) : next(std::move(other.next)), elem(std::move(other.elem))
{
}
```

Please take care, I am not sure about the exact template Syntax above.

It is a good thing that you obey the rule of five, but if you do not want to do anything special in some of the constructors, assignment operators or destructor, then think about making them `= default`. That makes things easier and safer for you.

Comment: Wow! It really is that simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we know about `E` is there is `default c-tor`, else the code won't compile.

In general move c-tor will look like *Werner Henze* suggested. However I suggest you reset the pointer too.

```
template <typename E>
Node::Node<E>( Node<E> && other ) :
               next(std::move(other.next)),   // line 1
               elem(std::move(other.elem)){   // line 2
        // change to NULL for pre C++11
        other.next = nullptr;  // line 3
}
```

## What is going on here?

here is the explanation:

- **line 1** - we move the pointer. Pointer can not be really moved. It is copied. However is good habit to keep `std::move`, just to "show the intention" you moving.
- **line 2** - we move the data. Here are possibilities here:

  - If `E` is `movable` class, this move the class.
  - If `E` is not `move-able` class, but is `copy-able` (simplest example is `int`), copy is made.
  - If `E` is not `move-able` class, nor is `copy-able`. This won't compile.

After **line 2** is executed, `E` is in `valid` state, but must not be used because it might have different data inside. You can either destruct it or assign.

- **line 2** - here we reset the pointer, because `d-tor` might decide to do something with it.

## Alternative

Finally I will give you alternative code for `move c-tor` - using `swap`.

It probably will be slower, but for educational purpose is OK.

```
template <typename E>
Node::Node<E>( Node<E> && other ){
      // "this" class is created now.

      using std::swap;
      swap(next, other.next);
      swap(elem, elem);
}
```

## Final note:

You do not need `{}` here:

```
private:
    E elem{};       //datatype independent element
```

this is enought:

```
private:
    E elem;       //datatype independent element
```